# MacOS shell script to move files based on tag

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I am trying to write a shell script so that I can move school files from one destination to another based on the input. I download these files from a source like canvas and want to move them from my downloads based on the tag I assign, to the path for my course folder which is nested pretty deep thanks to how I stay organized. Unfortunately, since I store these files in my OneDrive school account, I am unable to eliminate some spacing issues but I believe I have accounted for these. Right now the script is the following:

```
if [ "$1" = "311" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/311/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "411" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/411/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "516" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/516/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "530" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/530/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "599" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/599/folder/$2'"

fi

files=$(mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags='$1'' -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads)
#declare -a files=$(mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags='$1'' -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads)
#mv $files $course
#echo "mv $files $course"
#echo $course

for file in $files
#for file in "${files[@]}"
do 
    #echo $file
    #echo $course
    mv $file $course
done
```

Where $1 is the tag ID and first part of path selection, and $2 is what week number folder I want to move it to. The single quotation marks are there to take care of the spacing in the filepath. I could very easily do this in python but I'm trying to expand my capabilities some. Every time I run this script I get the following message:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I initially tried to just move them all at once (per the first mv command that's commented out) and got this error, then tried the for loop, and array but get the same error each time. However, when I uncomment the echo statements in the for loop and manually try to move each one by copying and pasting the paths to the command line, it works perfectly. My best guess is something to do with the formatting of the variable "files", since

```
echo "mv $files $course"
```

indicates the presence of a newline character or separator between each file it saves.

I'm sure it's something super simple that I'm missing since I just started trying to pick up shell scripting last week, but nothing I have been able to find online has helped me resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `files` variable assignment and for loop with one command make this the script:

```
if [ "$1" = "311" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/311/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "411" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/411/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "516" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/516/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "530" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/530/folder/$2'"

elif [ "$1" = "599" ];
then
    course="'/path/to/599/folder/$2'"

fi

mv -t $course $(mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags='$1'' -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g)
```

The `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g` command simply replaces the newline characters with spaces, and the `-t` option for `mv` simply makes `mv` take the destination as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting rather confused about how quoting works in the shell. First rule: quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. For example, you use:

```
course="'/path/to/311/folder/$2'"
...
mv $file $course
```

When you set `course` this way, the double-quotes are treated as shell syntax (i.e. they change how what's between them is parsed), but the single-quotes are stored as part of the variable's value, and will thereafter be treated as data. When you use this variable in the `mv` command, it's actually looking for a directory literally named single-quote, and under that a directory named "path", etc. Instead, just put the appropriate quotes for how you want it parsed *at that point*, and then double-quotes around the variable when you use it (to prevent probably-unwanted word splitting and wildcard expansion). Like this:

```
course="/path/to/311/folder/$2"
...
mv "$file" "$course"    # This needs more work -- see below
```

Also, where you have:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags='$1'' -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads
```

that doesn't really make any sense. You've got a single-quoted section, `'kMDItemUserTags='` where the quotes have no effect at all (single-quotes suppress all special meanings that characters have, like `$` introducing variable substitution, but there aren't any characters there with special meanings, so no reason for the quotes), followed by `$` *without* double-quotes around it, meaning that *some* special characters (whitespace and wildcards) in its value will get special parsing (which you probably don't want), followed by a zero-length single-quoted string, `''`, which parses out to exactly nothing. You want the `$1` part in double-quotes; some people also include the rest of the string in the double-quoted section, which has no effect at all. In fact, other than the `$2` part (and the spaces between parameters), you can quote or not however you want. Thus, any of these would work equivalently:

```
mdfind kMDItemUserTags="$1" -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads
mdfind "kMDItemUserTags=$1" -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads
mdfind "kMDItemUserTags=$1" '-onlyin' '/Users/user/Downloads'
mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags'="$1" '-'"only"'in' /'Users'/'user'/'Down'loads
...etc
```

Ok, next problem: parsing the output from `mdfind` from a series of characters into separate filepaths. This is actually tricky. If you put double-quotes around the resilting string, it'll get treated as one long filepath that happens to contain some newlines in it (which is totally legal, but not what you want). If you *don't* double-quote it, it'll be split into separate filepaths based on whitespace (not just newlines, but also spaces and tabs -- and spaces are common within macOS filenames), *and* anything that looks like a wildcard will get expanded to a list of matching filenames. This tends to cause chaos.

The solution: there's one character than cannot occur in a filepath, the ASCII NULL (character code 0), and `mdfind -0` will output its list delimited with null characters. You can't put the result in a shell variable (they can't hold nulls either), but you can pass it through a pipe to, say, `xargs -0`, which will (thanks to the `-0` option) parse the nulls as delimiters, and build commands out of the results. There is one slightly tricky thing: you want `xargs` to put the filepaths it gets in the middle of the argument list to `mv`, not at the end like it usually does. The `-J` option lets you tell it where to add arguments. I'll also suggest two safety measures: the `-p` option to `xargs` makes it ask before actually executing the command (use this at least until you're sure it's doing the right thing), and the `-n` option to `mv`, which tells it not to overwrite existing files if there's a naming conflict. The result is something like this:

```
mdfind -0 kMDItemUserTags="$1" -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads | xargs -0 -p -J% mv -n % "$course"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good point to consider about filenames with whitespaces.
However the problem is that you are *not* quoting the filename in the `mv` command. Please take a look of a simple example below:

```
filename="with space.txt"
  => assign a variable to a filname with a space
touch "$filename"
  => create a file "with space.txt"
str="'$filename'"
  => wrap with single quotes (as you do) 
echo $str
  => yields 'with space.txt' and may look good, which is a pitfall
mv $str "newname.txt"
  => causes an error
```

The `mv` command above causes an error because the command is invoked with
three arguments as: `mv` `'with` `space.txt'` `newname.txt`. Unfortunately
the pre-quoting with single quotes is meaningless.

Instead, please try something like:

```
if [ "$1" = "311" ]; then
    course="/path/to/311/folder/$2"
elif [ "$1" = "411" ]; then
    course="/path/to/411/folder/$2"
elif [ "$1" = "516" ]; then
    course="/path/to/516/folder/$2"
elif [ "$1" = "530" ]; then
    course="/path/to/530/folder/$2"
elif [ "$1" = "599" ]; then
    course="/path/to/599/folder/$2"
else
    # illegal value in $1. do some error handling
fi
# the lines above may be simplified if /path/to/*folder/ have some regularity

mdfind "kMDItemUserTags=$1" -onlyin /Users/user/Downloads | while read -r file; do
    mv "$file" "$course"
done
# the syntax above works as long as the filenames do not contain newline characters
```